# How to make material-ui data-grid Toolbar and table colums header scrollable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i want to scroll horizontal my  Toolbar items when i scroll horizontal my datagrid table items. right now they are scrollable but they are separate. i want if i scroll toolbar items then datagrid items should scroll horizontal. if i scroll datagrid items then toolbar items should scroll too.
please check code sandbox link.. Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/69495064-is-there-a-chance-to-change-toolbar-names-material-ui-datagrid-forked-6kk5yh?file=/demo.tsx

[image]

i am also pasting the code here too

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { useDemoData } from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";

function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", overflow: "auto" }}>
      <p style={{ minWidth: "30%" }}>Course Name1:</p>
      <p style={{ minWidth: "30%" }}>Course Name2:</p>
      <p style={{ minWidth: "30%" }}>Course Name3:</p>
      <p style={{ minWidth: "30%" }}>Course Name4:</p>
      <p style={{ minWidth: "30%" }}>Course Name5:</p>
      <p style={{ minWidth: "30%" }}>Course Name6:</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function CustomToolbarGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 10,
    maxColumns: 10
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        {...data}
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

incase if someone face this same issue i fix this without using Toolbar . now i am using renderHeader. so i pass all texts there .